# How to hide specific folder using AWS STS AssumeRole session policy?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, assume-role, aws-iam-policy

I have created STS AssumeRole session token with adding policy document as List only to specific folders, but how we can hide on showing remaining folders which doesn’t have access?

**Example:**
Let consider I have AWS s3 object paths `s3://<bucketName>/folder1/{files…}` & `s3://<bucketName>/folder2/{files…}`

I generated STS token having *Action* (i.e., `S3:List*`) and filter *Condition* policy  ( i.e. `"StringEquals" : “folder1/*”` )

In my application using AWS SDK (Javascript) with above generated STS session token. If I try to List objects under Key (s3:///), response returning both `folder1/` & `folder2/`.

How can I hide `folder2/` based on current STS session policy?
(***Note***: Eventhough we have restrict List access to deep dive into `folder2/`. I don't my SDK to show `folder2/` in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

`s3:List` is a bucket-level operation, so it will list all the contents as long as the permissions allow it.

You can deny access to `folder2/` by adding a condition like you said. However, that folder will still be visible if [ListBucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) is called in the above directory.